# Footer not appearing in Chrome while it is working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, css-print

In CSS media print, I want two headers and two footers to appear in all the pages. I have written the code here and it is working fine while printing in IE but in Chrome, the "Footer within the text" is not appearing in first two pages. It shows only in the last page. What correction do I need to do to get the print correct in chrome too.

```css
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-before: avoid;
  }
}

@page {
  size: 100%;
  margin: 70pt 60pt 70pt;
  page-break-after: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  font: small-caps;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
}

.footer {
  font: small-caps;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
}

.inside-header {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida      Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.inside-footer {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida  Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 70px;
}

.header-space,
.footer-space {
  height: 25px;
}

.inside-header-space,
.inside-footer-space {
  height: 100px;
}

.inside-header {
  height: 50px;
  position: auto;
}

.inside-footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-after: auto;
}

div. page {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="text-align: center;"> This is a page header. </div>
<div class="header-space"></div>
<div class="footer" style="text-align: right;"> This is a page footer. </div>
<div class="footer-space"></div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="inside-header" style="text-align:    center;"> This header is within text. </div>
        <div class="inside-header-space" style="text-align: center;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="page" style="line-height:2; align-self:  auto;">
          <h2>Page 1 : Contains Content</h2>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt metus eu consectetur rutrum. Praesent tempor facilisis dapibus. Aliquam cursus diam ac vehicula pulvinar. Integer lacinia non odio et condimentum. Aenean faucibus cursusmi,
            sed interdum turpis sagittis a. Quisque quis pellentesque mi. Ut erat eros, posuere sed scelerisque ut, pharetra vitae tellus. Suspendisse ligula sapien, laoreet ac hendrerit sit amet, viverra vel mi. Pellentesque faucibus nisl et dolorpharetra,
            vel mattis massa venenatis. Integer congue condimentum nisi, sed tincidunt velit tincidunt non. Nulla sagittis sed lorem pretium aliquam. Praesent consectetur volutpat nibh, quis pulvinar est volutpat id. Cras maximus odio posuere suscipit
            venenatis. Donec rhoncus scelerisque metus, in tempus erat rhoncus sed. Morbi massa sapien, porttitor id urna vel, volutpat blandit velit. Cras sit amet sem eros. Quisque commodo facilisis tristique. Proin pellentesque sodales rutrum.Lorem
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt metus eu consectetur rutrum. Praesent tempor facilisis dapibus. Aliquam cursus diam ac vehicula pulvinar. Integer lacinia non odio et condimentum. Aenean faucibus cursus mi,
            sed interdum turpis sagittis a. Quisque quis pellentesque mi. Ut erat eros, posuere sed scelerisque ut, pharetra vitae tellus. Suspendisse ligula sapien, laoreet ac hendrerit sit amet, viverra vel mi. Pellentesque faucibus nisl et dolorharetra,
            vel mattis massa venenatis. Integer congue condimentum nisi, sed tincidunt velit tincidunt non. Nulla sagittis sed lorem pretium aliquam. Praesent consectetur volutpat nibh, quis pulvinar est volutpat id. Cras maximus odio posueresuscipit
            venenatis. Donec rhoncus scelerisque metus, in tempus erat rhoncus sed. Morbi massa sapien, porttitor id urna vel, volutpat blandit velit. Cras sit amet sem eros. Quisque commodo facilisis tristique. Proin pellentesque sodales rutrum.Vestibulum
            purus neque, congue vel dapibus in, venenatis ut felis. Donec et ligula enim. Sed sapien sapien, tincidunt vitae lectus quis, ultricies rhoncus mi. Nunc dapibus nulla tempus nunc interdum, sed facilisis ex pellentesque. Nunc vel lorem leo.
            Cras pharetra sodales metus. Cras lacus ex, consequat at consequat vel, laoreet ac dui. Curabitur aliquam, sapien quis congue feugiat, nisi nisl feugiat diam, sed vehicula velit nulla ac nisl. Aliquam quis nisi euismod massa blandit pharetra
            nec eget nunc. Etiam eros ante, auctor sit amet quam vel, fringilla faucibus leo. Morbi a pulvinar nulla. Praesent sed vulputate nisl. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean commodo mollis
            iaculis. Maecenas consectetur enim vitae mollis venenatis. Ut scelerisque pretium orci id laoreet. In sit amet pharetra diam. Vestibulum in molestie lorem. Nunc gravida, eros non consequat fermentum, ex orci vestibulum orci, non accumsan sem
            velit ac lectus. Vivamus malesuada lacus nec velit dignissim, ac fermentum nulla pretium. Aenean mi nisi, convallis sed tempor in, porttitor eu libero. Praesent et molestie ante. Duis suscipit vitae purus sit amet aliquam. Vestibulum lectus
            justo, lobortis a purus a, dapibus efficitur metus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis dictum ex lorem. Suspendisse nec ligula consectetur magna hendrerit ullamcorper et eget mauris. Etiam vestibulum sodales diam, eget venenatis nunc luctus quis. Ut
            fermentum placerat neque nec elementum. Praesent orci erat, rhoncus vitae est eu, dictum molestie metus. Cras et fermentum elit. Aenean eget augue lacinia, varius ante in, ullamcorper dolor. Cras viverra purus non egestas consectetur. Nulla
            nec dolor ac lectus convallis aliquet sed a metus. Suspendisse eu imperdiet nunc, id pulvinar risus. Maecenas varius sagittis est, vel fermentum risus accumsan at. Vestibulum sollicitudin dui pharetra sapien volutpat, id convallis mi vestibulum.
            Phasellus commodo sit amet lorem quis imperdiet. Proin nec diam sed urna euismod ultricies at sed urna. Quisque ornare, nulla et vehicula ultrices, massa purus vehicula urna, ac sodales lacus leo vitae mi. Sed congue placerat justo at placerat.
            Aenean suscipit fringilla vehicula. Quisque iaculis orci vitae arcu commodo maximus. Maecenas nec nunc rutrum, cursus elit quis, porttitor sapien. Sed ac hendrerit ipsum, lacinia fringilla velit. Donec ultricies feugiat dictum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="inside-footer" style="text-align: center;">This is a footer within text.</div>
        <div class="inside-footer-space" style="text-align: center;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: well actually it works perfectly but only when you are in full screen. Check you snippet and go full page

Comment: @xmaster: Thanks for your immediate reply, but I could not understand what exactly I need to do!

Comment: don't give it a position

Comment: https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

Comment: @xmaster I got your point, moreover there was some other flaw too in my code. It's working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: @yunzen Yes I followed that too but I had some additional requirement. Thank you.